# Accumulating results of a recursive function in python

Tags: python, recursion

Consider the following function to permute numbers in a list:

```
def permute(numbers, N=0):
    # base case
    if N == len(numbers):
        print numbers
        return

    for i in range(len(numbers)-N):

        # swapping relevant elements
        element=numbers.pop(N+i)
        numbers.insert(N,element)

        # recursive call
        permute(numbers, N+1)

        # swapping back relevant elements when backtracking
        element=numbers.pop(N)
        numbers.insert(N+i,element)


numbers=[1,2,3]
permute(numbers)
```

Why is it that when I run the above code, it produces the correct output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

but when I'm trying to accumulate the result to a list:

```
def permute(numbers, permutations, N=0):
    # base case
    if N == len(numbers):
        print numbers
        permutations.append(numbers)
        return

    for i in range(len(numbers)-N):

        # swapping relevant elements
        element=numbers.pop(N+i)
        numbers.insert(N,element)

        # recursive call
        permute(numbers, permutations, N+1)

        # swapping back relevant elements when backtracking
        element=numbers.pop(N)
        numbers.insert(N+i,element)


numbers=[1,2,3]
permutations=[]
permute(numbers, permutations)

print "-----------"
for p in permutations:
    print p
```

The output is this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
-----------
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Not quite what I expected...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but consider using the standard `itertools.permutations` method.

Comment: This is homework, I had to implement it myself...

Comment: there is a much simpler way http://pastebin.com/tm9Dw9t4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the items you're appending to `permutations` are actually the same list. Changing one changes all of the others. The easiest fix for this is to make a copy of the list before appending it, so future changes to `numbers` has no effect on the already-appended results.

```
def permute(numbers, permutations, N=0):
    # base case
    if N == len(numbers):
        print numbers
        permutations.append(numbers[:])
        return
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
---------
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.
They are indeed the same list, but isn't python's append supposed to deep-copy `numbers` with its new order?

Comment: I don't believe so. That claim is not consistent with append's observed behavior, and it doesn't mention deep copying in `help(list.append)`. As a simpler demonstration, `a = [1,2,3]; b = []; b.append(a); b[0] is a` gives True, but we'd expect False if deep copying occurred.